# Django Template Tags -- Trying to Let Users Delete Own Comments

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm pretty new to Django. This seems really basic, but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here.

```
<div class="comment">
  <h2 class="commenter">{{ comment.user }}</h2>
  <p class="commentdate">{{ comment.created }}</p>
  <p class="commentbody">{{ comment.body }}</p>
  "{{ comment.user }}" "{{ user.username }}"
  {% ifequal commment.user user.username %}
  <p><a href="#">Delete comment</a></p>
  {% endifequal %}
</div>
```

I want a delete button to show up only if the logged in user is the same as the user who made a comment. {{ comment.user }} and {{ user.username }} are printing the same result (this is just a test line to see what's stored in these), but the {% ifequal comment.user user.username %} tag is evaluating as false for some reason. What am I doing wrong? Is it maybe a data type issue? If so, I'm not sure how to address that in template tags.

Comment: I am also quite new to Django, but as far as I know `isequal` tag is very old, and you have use simple `{% if comment.user == user.username  %} {% else %}{% endif %}` tag now.

Answer (score 0):

Via django template, you have access to `request`

Basically  you can access the logged in user with `request`.
If `comment.user` is an instance of `django.auth.models.User`.

The logic can be:

> **NOTE:** This doesn't prevent user deleting others comments, all the logics need to be done in your back end. Make sure the current user owns the comment

```
<div class="comment">
    <h2 class="commenter">{{ comment.user }}</h2>
    <p class="commentdate">{{ comment.created }}</p>
    <p class="commentbody">{{ comment.body }}</p>

    "{{ comment.user }}" "{{ user.username }}"

     {% if request.user == comment.user %}
         <p><a href="#">Delete comment</a></p>
     {% endif %}

     <!-- or with ifequal templatetag -->
     {% ifequal comment.user request.user %}
         <p><a href="#">Delete comment</a></p>
     {% endifequal %}


</div>
```

Comment: request.user does indeed hold the same thing as comment.user, but again, the template tag is evaluating as false. I'm thinking this must be a data type issue. But is there a way to convert in the template tag, or do I need to adjust elsewhere?

Comment: Because you compare user instance with the `usersame`.. they are differents

Comment: Why do you want to do it with `templatetag` whereas it's possible and better with `request`

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to Django. I'm trying to figure out for the first time how to allow users to delete their own comments, blog posts, and user profiles, but I honestly have no idea where to start. I'm trying to get these template tags to work so I have a button to press to test if the back end is working (once I figure that part out).

Comment: got it, i edited my answer, the second option will work with `ifequal`, the `templatetag` that you want

Comment: Thanks for you comments, but for some reason it's still evaluating as false. I'm guessing it's a data type issue, but it seems like it's not as simple as just casting within the template, so I guess I need to hit the books to get a better understanding of how I would allow users to delete their content on the front end.

Comment: `request.user`  not `user` ---> `ifequal comment.user request.user`